# Trouble Integrating Speech Recognition into PysimpleGUI + Search Bot

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pysimplegui, pyttsx

I've recently tried my hand at a simple search engine using TTS. However, I tried integrating Speech to text for the search field in Pysimple GUI and I have hit a road block.

I'm able to get the pysimpleGUI to recognize the words that I say, and search the results.However, the search engine mechanism doesn't recognize my speech to text as the value that I input and only gives me back the first letter that I used in my speech to text.

For example, I said "What is the weather like today" and it returned me back the definition of the letter "W"

These are the packages that I used:

```
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyttsx3
```

## All the stuff inside Pysimple GUI text window.

```
layout = [  [sg.Text('Welcome Back Sir')],
            [sg.Text('How can I be of assistance'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.ReadButton('Speak'), sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

window = sg.Window('Pybot', layout)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```

## Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
        break
    if event == 'Speak':
        with m as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            values = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
            print(values)
    try:
        wiki_res = wikipedia.summary(values[0], sentences=2)
        wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
        engine.say(wolfram_res)
        sg.PopupNonBlocking("Wolfram Result: "+wolfram_res,"Wikipedia Result: "+wiki_res)
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError:
        wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
        engine.say(wolfram_res)
        sg.PopupNonBlocking(wolfram_res)
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
        engine.say(wolfram_res)
        sg.PopupNonBlocking(wolfram_res)
    except:
        wiki_res = wikipedia.summary(values[0], sentences=2)
        engine.say(wiki_res)
        sg.PopupNonBlocking(wiki_res)

    engine.runAndWait()

    print (values[0])

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use same variable `values`, so `values[0]` is `w`.

```py
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
...
            values = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
...
```

revised code

[image]

```py
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
        break
    # print(event, values)
    if event == 'Speak':
        with m as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            value = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
            print(value)
            window[0].update(value)
            window.write_event_value('Ok', '')
    elif event == 'Ok':
        if values[0] == '':
            continue
        try:
            wiki_res = wikipedia.summary(values[0], sentences=2)
            wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
            engine.say(wolfram_res)
            sg.PopupNonBlocking("Wolfram Result: "+wolfram_res,"Wikipedia Result: "+wiki_res)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError:
            wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
            engine.say(wolfram_res)
            sg.PopupNonBlocking(wolfram_res)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
            wolfram_res = next(client.query(values[0]).results).text
            engine.say(wolfram_res)
            sg.PopupNonBlocking(wolfram_res)
        except:
            wiki_res = wikipedia.summary(values[0], sentences=2)
            engine.say(wiki_res)
            sg.PopupNonBlocking(wiki_res)

        engine.runAndWait()

window.close()
```

It will block when audio processing, maybe you can try multi-threaded programming, otherwise GUI will no response sometime.

Comment: Hi Jason, 

After applying your revised comment, I managed to get the speech to text to register. However, I am now getting two results. "What is the weather like yesterday" returns the result for "W" and the desired result. 

What could be the problem? 

Thanks

Comment: Where you got "W" ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/peV9JmS

This is after running the code.

Comment: Your code is different ! and what 'client' is ? In Image, I see you still use same `values`.

Comment: The code after `try` not indent, so your got two popups. That image not after running my code, but yours.

Comment: Hi Jason, 

managed to fix the issue thanks for the help. Good day to you!